# automatic plant watering system using microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmega, atmel

I am trying to build an automatic plant watering system using ATmega16. We are using moisture sensor YL69 for our project. The following is the image of the moisture sensor we have used.

[image]

The circuit diagram of the project is as follows:
[image]

The following is the code fragment we used:

```
#include<avr/io.h>
int adc(void);
void pump(void);
int adc_value;
int main(void)
 {
  DDRC=0x01;                          //Defining PC0 as output
  ADCSRA=0x87;                    //Setting the mode of operation
  ADMUX=0x00;                     //Selection of channel and bit alignment
  while(1)
   {
     adc_value=adc();                //reading moisture level
     pump();                               //Pump activator routine
   }
   return 0;
 }

int adc(void)
{
   int lower_bits,higher_bits,result; 
   ADCSRA |= (1 << ADSC)|(1 << ADIF);  //Turn on conversion and clear flag
   while(ADCSRA & (1 << ADIF) == 0);  //wait for flag
   lower_bits=ADCL;
   higher_bits=ADCH;
   result=lower_bits|(higher_bits<<8);         //Accessing converted value by shifting
   return result;
 }

void pump(void)
 {
  if(adc_value>=700)                                //Pump ON trigger point
   {
     PORTC|=(1<<0);
   }
  else if(adc_value<=600)                        //Pump Off trigger point
   {
     PORTC&=~(1<<0);
   }
 }
```

Is there anything wrong in the code? Because after burning it, i am getting  low voltage(0.15) for wet soil and high voltage(4.84) for dry soil from the analog sensor input which is ok … but the problem is, I am **always** getting voltage like **0.7** (and sometimes like  0.15) at PC0  in both cases(I am using multimeter for measuring this). There in no change in the values for dry and wet soil at PC0.. in such case where is the actual problem? Is there anything wrong in the circuit design or in the code? And one more thing, can anyone please tell me the proper way of measuring the output value I am getting from PC0 which in turn is switching on/off the pump?

Another question is, I am using AVR programmer for 5V DC supply. In the above circuit design I have not made any connection  at pin MOSI,MISO,RESET and SCK (of ATmega 16) with AVR programmer. Will I have to make this?

Comment: Is that code written in Atmel Studio?

Comment: yes with Atmel Studio @BlueSky

Comment: Are you sure that the code is getting programmed into the chip?

Comment: I have used extreme burner for burning the hex file got from atmel studio into atmega16. I haven't got any error @Dave Tweed♦

Answer (score 1):

Have you measured this voltage with resistor detached? You should measure it relative to GND and then relative to +5V to make sure. Otherwise it is hard to determine wrongly configured pin.

Try to debug your code. Add 4-5 LEDs since you have many free pins and output highest bits of ADC to these LEDs.

Or output the ADC values to UART and read them via terminal.

**BTW, why AVCC is connected to +5 via capacitor?** Are you sure ADC is powered properly this way?

> In the above circuit design I have not made any connection at pin MOSI,MISO,RESET and SCK (of ATmega 16) with AVR programmer. Will I have to make this?

I do not understand. You need these connections when programming of course, but not when running :)

Comment: " Add 4-5 LEDs since you have many free pins and output highest bits of ADC to these LEDs.

Or output the ADC values to UART and read them via terminal.

"- Will you please clarify this a bit more. I haven't understood it prp\lperly @Rodion Gorkovenko

Comment: Well, before this could you answer the question about AVCC I outlined in bold? It looks like most strange thing in your schematics. Why haven't you wired it directly to +5?

Comment: well, is there anything wrong if I connect it through capacitor? I am not sure about it @Rodion Gorkovenko

Comment: The power to ADC simply would not be fed through capacitor. Capacitor do not conduct the current. So I believe ADC is not powered and is not working properly. Though it is a long time since I last read the manual for Atmega16. But you can read it right now to make sure how this pin should be connected. :)

Comment: should I have to connect the AVCC  to 5V using a low pass filter? @Rodion Gorkovenko

Comment: You can connect it directly if you do not need extra precise measurement. Low pass filter allows to reduce the effect of current peaks and gaps on the VCC line.

Comment: ok.. I will do it.. But is there anything wrong in the code? @Rodion Gorkovenko

Comment: will i always have to connect the reset pin(at 9) to vcc? @Rodion Gorkovenko

Comment: No, you can generally leave it unconnected. I believe manual says there is internal pull-up resistor so you simply duplicate this.

Comment: will you please tell me  is there anything wrong in the code?? @Rodion Gorkovenko

Comment: Just fix the schematics and plug in to check. I see no obvious errors in code though I have no compiler / simulator in my head (even as you and any other human) so it is not 100% guarantee.

Comment: " Add 4-5 LEDs since you have many free pins and output highest bits of ADC to these LEDs. Or output the ADC values to UART and read them via terminal. "- Will you please clarify this a bit more. I haven't understood it @Rodion Gorkovenko

Comment: We are getting 4.87V from dry soil and 0.15V from wet soil as input from sensor which is ok. For test purpose we have set an LED between PA0 and ground and the LED is glowing brightly. But for both dry and wet case I am getting near about 4.84V at PC0 output, which is not ok, but whatever,we were trying to check if the LED glows as before if we put it between PCO and ground, as we are getting 4.84V here. But the LED is not glowing now although there is voltage. why are we facing this?  Is the voltage we are getting at PC0 not enough? @Rodion Gorkovenko

Comment: "But the LED is not glowing now although there is voltage." If you have detached the resistor-transistor circuit, and have DDRC = 1 and PORTC = 1 then it should glow very welll (if you connect LED in proper direction between PC0 and GND via resistor of about 1k).

Comment: As about LED-s for debuuging. See, you have PD7...PD0 not used. Configure some of them as outputs DDRD = 0xFF for example. Then attach LED-s between each of them and GND (with 1k resistor for every LED to limit the current). If you have no 8 LEDs, attach whatever you have to only highest bits, say PD7..PD3.

Now you can write any byte to PORTD and visually see its highest bits. For example PORTD = (adc >> 2);

Comment: Any reason why a proper debugger can't be used?